# Unable to substitute redirection for redundant cat

Tags: bash, cut, io-redirection, xargs

```
cat  joined.txt | xargs -t -a <(cut --fields=1 | sort -u | grep -E '\S') -I{} --max-args=1 --max-procs=4 echo "mkdir -p imdb/movies/{}; grep '^{}' joined.txt  > imdb/movies/{}/movies.txt" | bash
```

The code above works but substituting the redundant cat at the start of the code with a redirection like below  doesn't work and leads to a cut input output error.

```
< joined.txt xargs -t -a <(cut --fields=1 | sort -u | grep -E '\S') -I{} --max-args=1 --max-procs=4 echo "mkdir -p imdb/movies/{}; grep '^{}' joined.txt  > imdb/movies/{}/movies.txt" | bash
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In either case, it is the `cut` command inside the process substitution (and not `xargs`) that should be reading from `joined.txt`, so to be completely safe, you should put either the pipe or the input redirection inside the the process substitution. Actually, neither is necessary; `cut` can just take `joined.txt` as an argument.

```
xargs -t -a <( cat joined.txt | cut ... ) ... | bash
```

or

```
xargs -t -a <( cut -f1 joined.txt | ... ) ... | bash
```

However, it would be clearest to skip the process substitution altogether, and pipe the output of that pipeline to `xargs`:

```
cut -f joined.txt | sort -u | grep -E '\S' | xargs -t ...
```

Comment: There is a history to the way I arrived at the solution presented in the problem. I was trying to make the content of joined.txt available to the grep commmand. This would enable me to stick the xargs on the end of the pipeline that produces joined.txt (which is a  400MB file). As far as I can see the mkdir preceding the grep stops this from being possible, do you see a way it could be done?

Comment: That's not going to work. `grep` presumably wants the complete contents of what `joined.txt` will be, but you would only be feeding parts of it to each `grep` as the file is generated.